# I am a word with the following properties. Find me and solving riddles might be one of your qualities

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, anagram

> > **Riddle me this:**
>
> *I am a word with the following properties.*
>
> *Find me and solving riddles might be one of your qualities.*
>
> *An anagram is what you must be to execute me.*
>
> *An anagram is a form of art if you then add the letter C.*
>
> *An anagram is a number of items if you rid the last two.*
>
> *An anagram is a sound if you then add E, H and W.*
>
> *An anagram does not move if you add the letter L.*
>
> *But, do not forget, you must then discard E and N as well.*
>
> *I have six envelopes, but you cannot write in them.*
>
> *Is it too difficult to try and guess what word I am?*

---

I made up this riddle for fun, as well as the following poem.

*My riddles have not been as hard as I thought they would be.* 
 *So I made this riddle a lot harder, well, hopefully.* 
 *(In my riddles, I also love to incorporate a bit of poetry.)*

Hope you enjoy!

Hints for the answer are below.

---

**Hint:**

> *I do not require much, just only the sides;*
>  *But if you are not fully aware, then trouble may decide.*

---

**Edit:**

I added the word `then` to lines $3$ and $6$ in order to avoid confusion of when to add letters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your word is

> LISTEN.

Find me and solving riddles might be one of your qualities.

> (I don't think there's anything fancy going on in this line.)

An anagram is what you must be to execute me.

> SILENT. (Hard to listen if you're making a lot of noise.)

An anagram is a form of art if you add the letter C.

> STENCIL.

An anagram is a number of items if you rid the last two.

> LIST.

An anagram is a sound if you then add E, H and W.

> WHISTLE. (Adding EHW to our last word, rather than to the original LISTEN.)

An anagram does not move if you add the letter L.
But, do not forget, you must discard E and N as well.

> STILL. (Adding L just to LIST, as with the previous word.)

I have six envelopes, but you cannot write in them.

> Well, you have six *letters*, anyway. Not sure about the envelopes as such.

Is it too difficult to try and guess what word I am?

> I hope not.

Comment: Nicely done!  Got me by 32 seconds :)

Comment: Regarding the "E, H and W" part, I added the word *then* to emphasise that we are adding the letters to the world LIST as opposed to LISTEN. But still, I have no idea how you got that! Good job!! You have a serious talent!

Comment: That one and the one that follows it were the way in, for what it's worth. W is a fairly uncommon letter.

Comment: @puzzle-guesser Sorry! I wasn't intending to scoop anyone :-).

Comment: If you want, you can try to explain the hint :)

Comment: @user477343 Answerers putting their solutions in spoiler tags is of little benefit if people then give the answer away in the comments.  I've noticed you mention the solution in comments to a number of your puzzles; please avoid doing this. If you need to allude to the answer at all, do try being indirect about it instead of saying or referencing it directly, or using [ROT-13](http://www.rot13.com/) encoding or similar if you must, to preserve the mystery for future would-be solvers. :)

Comment: @Rubio ok. Sorry about that. Thanks for letting me know :)